# TypoScript select where dataWrap dynamically filled by fluid variable possible?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have my own extension with which a frontend user can create own records. On a user detail page then all entries of the user should be displayed.

In my "Show" template I have a variable {user.uid} with which I come to the User UID. How do I get that into my typoscript?

**Typoscript**

```
lib.getuserItems = CONTENT
lib.getuserItems {
table = tx_myext_domain_model_item
select {
    selectFields = crdate,image,message,uid,deleted
    pidInList = 2
    orderBy = crdate DESC
    where.data = 
    where.dataWrap = ((tx_myext_domain_model_item.author_ident = '{user.uid}')) AND deleted = 0 AND NOT tx_myext_domain_model_item.parent_item
}
```

**Fluid**

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.getuserItems" data="{user.uid}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a single value (so not an array or object), it is available as the `current` value in TypoScript. So your TypoScript should be:

```
lib.getuserItems = CONTENT
lib.getuserItems {
  table = tx_myext_domain_model_item
  select {
    selectFields = crdate,image,message,uid,deleted
    pidInList = 2
    orderBy = crdate DESC
    where.current = 1
    // ensure it's an integer
    where.intval = 1
    where.wrap = ((tx_myext_domain_model_item.author_ident = '|')) AND deleted = 0 AND NOT tx_myext_domain_model_item.parent_item
  }
}
```

Comment: Added `where.intval = 1` in order to make sure it's really and integer and avoid (possible) SQL injection...